# Visualforce Pages in edit page layout on Accounts

Tags: page-layout

Can someone tell me why I do not see "Visualforce Pages" in the edit layout view of Accounts while I can see Visualforce Pages in the same view for Contacts? I can see Fields, Buttons, Custom Links, Related Lists, and Actions but no Visualforce Pages. How can I add a VF page on an Accounts record - I was neatly able to do so on Contacts but not on Accounts cause the option doesn't exist.

Just to make myself clearer:

In the Contact Layout, I see to the extreme left:

Fields Buttons Custom Links Visualforce Pages (On clicking this, you see the created Visualforce pages to the right that you can easily drag and drop) Related Lists Actions

When I look at the same thing for Accounts though, this is what I see:

Fields Buttons Custom Links Related Lists Actions

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm adding the "Account" controller. <apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false"> <apex:image url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers={! account.Location__Latitude__s },{! account.Location__Longitude__s }&zoom=13&size=320x240&sensor=false"/> </apex:page> The VisualForce Pages menu does not appear in the menu for the Page Layout.
And the Page I'm having have the flag for available for mobile app.
Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that your VF page which you have done for accounts doesnt have a standardcontroller="Account" and your Vf page for contact has standardcontroller="contact"

If you want your VF pages to be available on your pagelayout then you need to define the standardcontroller as that object which you want the page to be embeded in.